# How to caclulate regression line slope line for pearsons for multiple correlations when we have r and p value in R

Tags: r, regression, p-value

I am new to R, and I need to calculate regression lines for multiple correlations where I have p and r values obtained already.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular provide a full reproducible example including input and code.

Comment: The slope is equal to the correlation coefficient times the standard deviation of y divided by the standard deviation of x. To estimate the y-intercept you need the means of x and y. Without the means and standard deviations you cannot compute the regression line.